# Python VLC binding- playing a playlist

Tags: python, mp3, vlc, playlist, audio-player

I was wondering if it is possible to open(play) a music playlist 
( .m3u file) with the use of vlc.py ? I searched for an answer but could not find it. I managed to play a simple mp3 file, even a mp3 stream, but I dont have any luck with the playlists. Can you help me, give me some example code? I want to be able to go through tracks( Next and Previous) within my python program. Thans in advance

Comment: Your going to have to code your own playlist system or find one thats already available.

Comment: what do you mean my own system? VLC player (with GUI) can play .m3u files and go to the next track,previous track... I wanted to know how it can be done with vlc.py module...

Comment: @NatkoKraševac Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a "**very**" rough mock up of some code that I wrote for something else, adapted to your question.
It should allow you, using vlc.py, to play streamed audio, an m3u audio playlist and an mp3 file.
As I said it is **very** rough code but it should point you in the right direction.
Hope it helps.

```
import requests
import vlc
from time import sleep
urls = [
    'http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/aacplus/live.pls?service=acbb',
    'file:///home/rolf/test.m3u',
    'file:///home/rolf/happy.mp3',
    'http://statslive.infomaniak.ch/playlist/energy90s/energy90s-high.mp3/playlist.pls',
    'http://streaming.radio.rtl2.fr/rtl2-1-44-128',
    ]

playlists = set(['pls','m3u'])

Instance = vlc.Instance()

for url in urls:
    ext = (url.rpartition(".")[2])[:3]
    test_pass = False    
    try:
        if url[:4] == 'file':
            test_pass = True
        else:
            r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            test_pass = r.ok
    except Exception as e:
        print('failed to get stream: {e}'.format(e=e))
        test_pass = False
    else:
        if test_pass:
            print('Sampling for 15 seconds')
            player = Instance.media_player_new()
            Media = Instance.media_new(url)
            Media_list = Instance.media_list_new([url])
            Media.get_mrl()
            player.set_media(Media)
            if ext in playlists:
                list_player = Instance.media_list_player_new()
                list_player.set_media_list(Media_list)
                if list_player.play() == -1:
                    print ("Error playing playlist")
            else:
                if player.play() == -1:
                    print ("Error playing Stream")
            sleep(15)
            if ext in playlists:
                list_player.stop()
            else:
                player.stop()

        else:
            print('error getting the audio')
```

Answer (score 5):

Just change the **path**,your good to go..

```
from vlc import Instance
import time
import os

class VLC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Player = Instance('--loop')

    def addPlaylist(self):
        self.mediaList = self.Player.media_list_new()
        path = r"C:\Users\dell5567\Desktop\engsong"
        songs = os.listdir(path)
        for s in songs:
            self.mediaList.add_media(self.Player.media_new(os.path.join(path,s)))
        self.listPlayer = self.Player.media_list_player_new()
        self.listPlayer.set_media_list(self.mediaList)
    def play(self):
        self.listPlayer.play()
    def next(self):
        self.listPlayer.next()
    def pause(self):
        self.listPlayer.pause()
    def previous(self):
        self.listPlayer.previous()
    def stop(self):
        self.listPlayer.stop()
```

Create a object

```
player = VLC()
```

Add playlist

```
player.addPlaylist()
```

Play the song

```
player.play()
time.sleep(9)
```

Play the next song

```
player.next()
time.sleep(9)
```

Pause the song

```
player.pause()
time.sleep(9)
```

Resume the song

```
player.play()
time.sleep(9)
```

Previous song

```
player.previous()
time.sleep(9)
```

Stop the song

```
player.stop()
```