# Media List in Python VLC

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

I need to write a program in Python that will play video files from a folder in the VLC player, using the Linux OS. These files must be in the playlist. Code:

```
import vlc

mrl1 = '....1.3gp'
mrl2 = '....2.3gp'

Instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=-1', '--fullscreen', '--mouse-hide-timeout=0')

MediaList = Instance.media_list_new()
MediaList.add_media(Instance.media_new(mrl2))
MediaList.add_media(Instance.media_new(mrl1))

list_player = Instance.media_list_player_new()
list_player.set_media_list(MediaList)

list_player.next()

player.play()
```

The problem is that after running the first video, the player closes. I think that it does not add the second video to the list.

1. How to add a video to a playlist in Python's binding for LibVLC?
2. Is there a utility function that plays all the videos in a folder?
   UPD: I've created a playlist, and ran it to test in VLC player. Playing only the first video. After VLC is also closed. What is rhe problem?

Comment: UPD: I've created a playlist, and ran it to test in VLC player. Playing only the first video. After VLC is also closed. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to put it into a loop, which waits for each song to finish playing. For example, try this code

```
import vlc
import time

mrl1 = '....1.3gp'
mrl2 = '....2.3gp'

song_list = [mrl1,mrl2]
instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=-1', '--fullscreen', '--mouse-hide-timeout=0')
for song in song_list:
    player = instance.media_player_new()
    media = instance.media_new(song)
    
    media.get_mrl()
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()
    playing = set([1,2,3,4])
    time.sleep(1)
    duration = player.get_length() / 1000
    mm, ss = divmod(duration, 60)

    while True:
        state = player.get_state()
        if state not in playing:
            break
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in the VLC or OS. I have reinstalled the OS and install vlc. It worked. 
Do you know how to specify the folder where you need to play all the videos?

Answer (score 1):

Use while/for loop which will iterate through media list one by one. May be in this case pointer is pointing to only first video.

Edit 1:

[Use of For Loop] ([Python VLC binding- playing a playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440708/python-vlc-binding-playing-a-playlist)) Refer answer section of this question. For loop is used to iterate through url's (which is media list in this case).

Comment: "UPD: I've created a playlist, and ran it to test in VLC player. Playing only the first video. After VLC is also closed."  The problem is probably in the VLC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669571/how-to-import-vlc-plugins-in-to-python-script

Comment: check this question. In this example author is using while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but to whomever it may help in the future. I tried both ways, the accepted answer and a for loop. I found that using MediaList with MediaListPlayer was a lot more efficient. Almost twice as much!

For this problem, you could do something like (Python 3.4+):

```
import time
from pathlib import Path

import vlc


def create_media_list(vlc_instance, filenames):
    media_list = vlc_instance.media_list_new()
    for f in filenames:
        media_list.add_media(f)
    return media_list


filenames = list(Path("dir_of_music").iterdir())

instance = vlc.Instance()
player = instance.media_list_player_new()

media_list = create_media_list(instance, filenames)
player.set_media_list(media_list)
player.play()

while player.is_playing():
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm sure it could be made more efficient. But this would would great and be more memory efficient than the accepted answer. This will also play through all the media in the directory.